# C#: get information about computer in domain

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

What classes should I use in C# in order to get information about a certain computer in my network? (Like who is logged on that computer, what Operating System is running on that computer, what ports are opened etc)

Comment: Are you trying to run this code on the target machine? or are you trying to run this from your computer and get information about another machine over the network?

Comment: I want to run the code from my computer to get info about another machine over the network, knowing its IP

Comment: Provided example of remote WMI query in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMI Library and here is a [VB.net example](http://www.siccolo.com/Articles/CodeProject/Build_Local_Network_Browser/Build_Local_Network_Browser.html). It shouldn't be difficult to convert it to C#

Answer (score 9):

Checkout [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management(loband).aspx) and [System.Management.ManagementClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass.aspx). Both are used for accessing WMI, which is how to get the information in question.

**Edit:** Updated with sample to access WMI from remote computer:

```
ConnectionOptions options;
options = new ConnectionOptions();

options.Username = userID;
options.Password = password;
options.EnablePrivileges = true;
options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

ManagementScope scope;
scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + ipAddress + "\\root\\cimv2", options);
scope.Connect();

String queryString = "SELECT PercentProcessorTime, PercentInterruptTime, InterruptsPersec FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor";

ObjectQuery query;
query = new ObjectQuery(queryString);

ManagementObjectSearcher objOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PercentProcessorTime");
dt.Columns.Add("PercentInterruptTime");
dt.Columns.Add("InterruptsPersec");

foreach (ManagementObject MO in objOS.Get())
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["PercentProcessorTime"] = MO["PercentProcessorTime"];
    dr["PercentInterruptTime"] = MO["PercentInterruptTime"];
    dr["InterruptsPersec"] = MO["InterruptsPersec"];

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

*Note: userID, password, and ipAddress must all be defined to match your environment.*

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using it in like an about box.  MSDN has the rest of the items you can all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace About_box
{
    public partial class About : Form
    {
        public About()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormLoad();
        }

        public void FormLoad()
        {
            SystemInfo si;
            SystemInfo.GetSystemInfo(out si);

            txtboxApplication.Text = si.AppName;
            txtboxVersion.Text = si.AppVersion;
            txtBoxComputerName.Text = si.MachineName;
            txtBoxMemory.Text = Convert.ToString((si.TotalRam / 1073741824)
                + " GigaBytes");
            txtBoxProcessor.Text = si.ProcessorName;
            txtBoxOperatingSystem.Text = si.OperatingSystem;
            txtBoxOSVersion.Text = si.OperatingSystemVersion;
            txtBoxManufacturer.Text = si.Manufacturer;
            txtBoxModel.Text = si.Model;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the code is run ON the machine in question; and will not work to get information about another machine on the network.

Comment: Where is this class (SystemInfo) defined?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the WMI library.