# How to get information about device drive

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, visual-c++

How to get information about device driver of the system .
like `Manufacturer,hardwareID,DriverAssembly Version  of that device` 
in .net programming

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get pc (system) information on windows machine - C# script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742389/get-pc-system-information-on-windows-machine-c-sharp-script)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question [Get PC System Information on Windows Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742389/get-pc-system-information-on-windows-machine-c-sharp-script), in particular the answer dealing with WMI and [How To Almost Everything IN WMI - Part 3: Hardware](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18268/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-3-Hardw) gets you what you need.

Comment: Also the System.Management answer to [Get Information about Computer in Domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971321/c-get-information-about-computer-in-domain) may help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above, ManagementObjectSearcher in c# is good enough. You just need to include 

using System.Management;

use the bellow code -

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher mos =
                   new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\root\cimv2", @"Select * From Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid = '"+deviceGuid+"'");
```